# what does " flagship smartphone" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

```
flagship: the ship that carries the commander of a fleet and flies his flag
```

Why `flagship` has anything to do with smartphone?

Comment: `flagship: the best or most important thing owned or produced by a particular organisation` (via Google)

Comment: not in traditional dictionary

Comment: The online versions of [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flagship), [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/flagship_1), and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flagship) (as well as plenty of other, 'nontraditional' dictionaries) all have a listing for *flagship* which specifies the relevant sense (one other than a literal ship carrying a flag).

Comment: @Tim what is a "traditional" dictionary?

Comment: I was surprised when I looked it up in my old American Heritage Dictionary. [**flagship** (n.) A ship bearing the flag of a fleet or a squadron commander.] Nothing more.

Comment: @ jimsug, old dictionary

Comment: Never try to figure out the nuances of a word simply by looking at a single dictionary, particularly an outdated one. [Here are a couple dozen for you](http://www.onelook.com/?w=flagship&ls=a_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first 20 Google I hits I see on *flagship smartphone* refer to the product which is the “flagship” of a specific manufacturer's line of smartphones: the most prestigious product, which “commands” the line as the focus of the company's marketing efforts and “flies the flag” of the company's brand.